# Не работают медиа-запросы

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста по какой причине не работают медиа-запросы? min-width работает, а max-width нет, не могу понять в чем проблема.

```
.menu_list {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .menu_list {
        background-color: rgba(155, 100, 142, 0.5);
    }
}
```

[image: DevTools]

Comment: Скинь подробнее свой код: html + css

Answer (score 0):

Добавь в head - `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Это должно помочь